# Event listener for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to try to make a simple real-time chat Rails web app, but I thought I would need some kind of let's call it "event listener" to be able to keep track of sent messages so the receiver user's feed get updated with the new message. Also, for the `Typing...` notice box.

I hope I explained myself.

I guess I could do it in a very troglodyte way to achieve this like follows:

`main.js`:

```
while(true) {
    $.get('/user-you-are-talking-to/are-there-new-messages', function(data) {
        if (data['are_there_new_messages'] === true) {
            $('#conversation').append(data['new_message']);
        }
    });
}
```

`conversation_controller.rb`:

```
# routed by /user-you-are-talking-to/are-there-new-messages'
def new_messages?
    unless @new_messages.blank?
        @json = []
        @json[:are_there_new_messages] = @new_messages.count > 0
        @json[:new_message]= @new_messages.shift
        render json: @json
    end
end
```

But well aside than the fact that I didn't test that code, a while loop and constant requests to the server seem like a really really bad idea, obviously.

I would like to know if Rails has a built-in feature like this, but as far as I know it doesn't, unlike frameworks I've worked with like Laravel. If there's not a built-in tool for this, how can I do this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real time apps are usually done with websockets.

https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine

https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket

Or if on a hosted service you can use a publish/subscribe service such as Pusher or PubNub.

Otherwise, you would do polling which is what you have in your example.

Comment: I am not familiar with these, could you show me a simple example of how the library and the websocket server works? And about the later... should this server replace the server I am using for Rails apps? For example when I am making apps just for fun I use the integrated web server webrick. Or this has nothing to do with it? I'm a bit confused with the concepts.

Comment: @dabadaba: aren't examples in their readmes clear enough, I wonder? And yes, to handle websockets people normally use a separate server, more capable of this. Certainly not webrick.

Comment: no, I don't understand what's going on in any of that code.

Comment: @dabadaba: yeah well, evented I/O is non-trivial stuff :)

Comment: I have seen it in java but quite some time ago, and I can't really easily see how to integrate that in a Rails app...

Comment: Check out Faye, they have examples

Comment: There are examples on github for the websocket gem. PubNub and Pusher provide an http API bridge to websockets, so you would send a message to them via HTTP and they would forward that message via websocket to their javascript client which you embed in your page. Then your code would display it on the site. This is also well documented on their respective websites. WebSockets is not a server but a protocol which allows you to send data to a client. HTTP is traditionally one way so you can't send data to the browser, only respond to a request.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking websocket is a protocol, but in the second link it says "EventMachine based WebSocket server" that's why I was asking about the server. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Yes, the protocol has both a server and client, but it does not replace your HTTP server, it's an additional server. In this case the gem would be the websocket server, the browser would be the client.

Comment: ah ok so server as in layer, not web server, got it confused ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 will come with [Action Cable](https://github.com/rails/actioncable):

> Action Cable seamlessly integrates websockets with the rest of your Rails application. It allows for real-time features to be written in Ruby in the same style and form as the rest of your Rails application, while still being performant and scalable. It's a full-stack offering that provides both a client-side JavaScript framework and a server-side Ruby framework. You have access to your full domain model written with ActiveRecord or your ORM of choice.

But while you're waiting for it, you can use a number of existing solutions, some of which @dinomix listed.

Another option is [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) (never used, but heard good things).

Comment: This is the kind of built-in feature I was talking about ;) Will have to wait though. Thanks for the info. Before posting this I was looking for a rails chat tutorial and found one using Faye. Will definetly work it out.